# Pycharm : Getting "Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine. Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit."

Tags: java, python, python-3.x, jvm, pycharm

I'm running java commands through my python script but getting **Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.**
 . The script is running through cmd.

I removed max and min heapsize in `pycharm.exe.vmoptions`. Also, degraded the java version but nothing worked.

Comment: Based on the information you provided -> `you did something wrong`. But joke aside. Could you please post a simple code snippet which shows what you are trying to do. Probably you pass wrong parameters. But this is only a guess.

Comment: Found solution : I downgraded my PyCharm version to 2.4 and now it's working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution : I downgraded my PyCharm version to 2.4 and now it's working.